# Creating a json obj from a string when working without a net connection?

Tags: javascript

I have a json object returned from a third party api, it looks like:

```
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8"}
```

I'm going to be working on my project without a network connection, so I have to do everything locally. How can I create an instance of a json object locally for testing? Say I copy the above string, can I do something like:

```
var json = null;
if (debugging_locally) {
    json = new jsonObj('{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8"}');
}
else {
    json = doAjaxCall();
}

doStuffWithJsonObj(json);
```

so I just want to create a json object from a stored string if debugging locally - how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
if (debugging_locally) {
    json = {"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is valid Javascript syntax.

Therefore, you can paste the JSON directly into the Javascript (not as a string) and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Resig's [post](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) as well. He covers some new JSON parsing capabilities that are currently in the JS engines of Safari, WebKit, Chrome, Firefox.

This way you can test a JSON string that you will be expecting from a web-service, your API etc.
eg.

instead of:

```
json = new jsonObj('{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8"}');
```

you could do:

```
json = JSON.parse('{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8"}');
```